# How can i make color animation (as a sci fi wall)

Tags: animation, shaders

I am new to Blender.

I made a wall but unfortunately i can't make the background material

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Congratulations on your wall. I can see some geometric background pattern right there. What exactly can't you make?

Comment: i want to make a material for the background plane

Comment: Again, what exactly? Absolute unclear what you're asking for. What in your image you call *background plane*? Mark it red or something, for now we can't really help...